# Builtin function to convert a string array to string

Tags: go

Suppose I have a string like this

`stringArray := []string{"Hello"}`

I would like to convert the array to a string such that

`s := func(stringArray)`

and s should be
`["Hello"]`

Is there a built in function that can do this for me in golang ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the json library:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
)

func toString(arr []string) string {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(arr)
    return string(b)
}
```

See [live demo](https://go.dev/play/p/3wLYlXAIBPa).